# Which layout would be the most appropriate in this case? Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, layout, xamarin.forms, responsive-design

I have the following problem, I create pairs of round buttons and title label on the right, I tried it on a StackLayout with Horizontal orientation, like this:

```
<StackLayout
     x:Name="ButtonsLayout"
     Orientation="Horizontal"
     Grid.Column="0"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
     Grid.Row="0"
     Grid.RowSpan="1">                    
 </StackLayout>
```

Then, this is the problem:

If the titles are not so large by coincidence the result is similar to my objective:

If the titles shown on the right of the buttons are too large to show it only in one line, I want to create the pairs of button & title under, I tried with a vertical orientation but puts them all in vertical and I want something like this:

The pairs of button & title are added by code.

Comment: What other layouts have you tried and why aren't those working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `FlexLayout`. You can specify lots of specifications for the way you want the controls to **Flow**. If you are wanting to **Bind** an items source to your layout, you can use a `BindableLayout` attached properties to bind a collection to the FlexLayout.

[FlexLayout Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout)

[BindableLayout Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)